# Sorting my multiple items in a tuple

Tags: python, sorting

I have the below list of tuple :

`[(6,7),(0,1),(2,4),(3,5),(2,3)]`

I have to first sort the tuple by their first element then if the first element is same i have to sort by the second element in descending order.

So the output should be : `[(0, 1), (2, 4), (2, 3), (3, 5), (6, 7)]`

I tried the below code for double sort:

```
from operator import itemgetter
intervals = [(6,7),(0,1),(2,4),(3,5),(2,3)]
sorted_intervals = sorted(sorted(intervals,key=itemgetter(0)),key=itemgetter(1),reverse=True)
print (sorted_intervals)
```

But it produces output like :

`[(6, 7), (3, 5), (2, 4), (2, 3), (0, 1)]`

which is not what I expect.

Can anyone give any clue how to solve this?

Answer (score -2):

you can achieve it by give negative value of second element

```
  data = [(6,7),(0,1),(2,4),(3,5),(2,3)]
  print sorted(data, key=lambda x: (x[0],-x[1]))
```

output:

```
[(0, 1), (2, 4), (2, 3), (3, 5), (6, 7)]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the output from this code is still `[(0, 1), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 5), (6, 7)]`, which is not what the OP wants

Comment: That's right. I want it to be reverse sorted the next time only for (2,3) and (2,4)

Comment: @SubhayanBhattacharya changed